# How to properly pass full file names to `cmd /c`?

Tags: cmd

I am trying to run a command in CMD prompt to get information from my SVN (TortoiseSVN 1.7.8). In a cmd prompt, I enter:

```
cmd /c C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe info C:\MyCode\CurrProj\Ry1
```

I get:

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

That makes sense as there is a space after 'C:\Program'. Ok, so if I enter:

```
cmd /c "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" info C:\MyCode\CurrProj\Ry1
```

then all works as expected. However, if the location (the last path) contains spaces:

```
cmd /c "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" info C:\MyCode\Curr Proj\Ry1
```

I get:

> svn: E155007: 'C:\MyCode\Curr' is not a working copy

So this means that the SVN command ran and used only part of the code location. So I added quotes around that path too:

```
cmd /c "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" info "C:\MyCode\Curr Proj\Ry1"
```

Which brings me back to error message:

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

WHAT?? Can someone explain why the CMD prompt is not interpreting this correctly? Shouldn't the last example launch a CMD prompt with the 'Close' option and run:

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" info "C:\MyCode\Curr Proj\Ry1"
```

If i run:
`"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" info "C:\MyCode\Curr Proj\Ry1"`
by itself, it works as expected, but this command will be run in a process that is created programatically in some C# code:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
                new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);
```

where `command = "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" info "C:\MyCode\Curr Proj\Ry1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excerpt from `cmd /help`:

```
If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line after
the switch is processed as a command line, where the following logic is
used to process quote (") characters:

    1.  If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters
        on the command line are preserved:

        - no /S switch
        - exactly two quote characters
        - no special characters between the two quote characters,
          where special is one of: &<>()@^|
        - there are one or more whitespace characters between the
          two quote characters
        - the string between the two quote characters is the name
          of an executable file.

    2.  Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is
        a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and
        remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving
        any text after the last quote character.
```

Comment: Hmmm... Never knew this. So how would one go about having paths that need quotes? UPDATE: I tried the following based on the above logic:cmd /c ""C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" info "C:\Nightly\ccb6p mfg\trunk"" - and it works. Since there are more than 2 quote characters, it strips the first and last ones which leaves: "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" info "C:\Nightly\ccb6p mfg\trunk", which is what I needed.

Comment: @radensb Sorry, I meant to elaborate on that but had to leave suddenly. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Don't put your arguments inline with the filename

```
using (Process p = new Process())
{
   p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
   p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c \"c:\\Program Files\\..blah\"";
   p.Start();
}
```

You also need to add quotes around the path by using escape characters

```
\" gives you "
```

Comment: Thank you Tsukasa, I am aware how to use escape characters to include quote characters in a string, but in my situation, I could not even get it to work when natively entering it in a CMD prompt window.

Comment: Ah ok I guess I didn't fully understand your issue. Seems like you have it corrected already

Answer (score 0):

You can also use old-style short names of file to execute (I know, it's not convenient, but may solve the problem, it's possible to get short name from long name, i.e. from dir /X):

```
cmd /c C:\Progra~1\Tortoi~1\bin\svn.exe info "C:\MyCode\Curr Proj\Ry1"
```